# I dont understand how this loop works, please explain how it prints the output

Tags: javascript, html

Doubt regarding the highlighted area]

[image]

Please help me clarify the doubt as how "text" helps in printing the next literal.

Comment: At least, show the [code instead of image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303816/4227915).

Comment: It is used to build a string... what is the hard part to understand. The string is made up of text and break elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=>The first line var str = "Hello"; creates a variable named str that has the string "Hello" stored in it.

=>The second line var arr = str.split(""); firstly creates a variable named arr that stores an array. This contents of this array are each of the characters in the string "Hello", this is as the method split is used on the variable that stores "Hello"

=>So what you have stored in arr is something that looks like this
| H | e | l | l | o |

=> Each part of the array has an index that can be used to access contents of the array so:

- arr[0] = H
- arr[1] = e
- arr[2] = l
- arr[3] = l
- arr[4] = o

=> The next two lines of your code creates two variables that will be used in your loop so:
- i is the variable that is used to control the loop
- text is the variable that stores the content that will be the content of your p element in your HTML document

=> Then you have the part that you have highlighted. This is a for loop. This for loop. With each cycle of the loop, your i variable, which is 0 at the start will increase by 1. Your loop will stop when your i variable reaches a value that is equal to the length of your array arr i.e. 5

=> So in the first cycle of your loop, i = 0 and therefore it passes the condition where i < 5. So you execute the statement in the loop and the text variable stores:

```
"H<br>"
```

Then i is incremented by 1 so i becomes 1

=> So in the second cycle of your loop, i = 1 and therefore it passes the condition where i < 5. So you execute the statement in the loop and the text variable stores:

```
"H<br>e<br>"
```

Then i is incremented by 1 so i becomes 2

=> So in the second cycle of your loop, i = 2 and therefore it passes the condition where i < 5. So you execute the statement in the loop and the text variable stores:

```
"H<br>e<br>l<br>"
```

Then i is incremented by 1 so i becomes 3

=> So in the fourth cycle of your loop, i = 3 and therefore it passes the condition where i < 5. So you execute the statement in the loop and the text variable stores:

```
"H<br>e<br>l<br>l<br>"
```

Then i is incremented by 1 so i becomes 4

=> So in the fifth cycle of your loop, i = 4 and therefore it passes the condition where i < 5. So you execute the statement in the loop and the text variable stores:

```
"H<br>e<br>l<br>l<br>o<br>"
```

Then i is incremented by 1 so i becomes 5

=> As i = 5, it fails to pass the condition and you exit the loop.

=> In the last statement, the content of the div with the id: demo is set to text i.e.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

becomes:

```
<p id="demo">
H<br>e<br>l<br>l<br>o<br>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for elaborating. Previously, I didnt get that output of text will be in concatenated form. Again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, the string "Hello" is turned into an array with 5 elements. `arr.length` is 5, because there are 5 elements.

`text` is a variable. As the loop progresses, the contents of `text` grow:

```
Loop    Value
0       ""
1       "H<br>"
2       "H<br>E<br>"
3       "H<br>E<br>L<br>"
4       "H<br>E<br>L<br>L<br>"
5       "H<br>E<br>L<br>L<br>O<br>"
```

When finished, the contents of variable `text` are:

```
"H<br>E<br>L<br>L<br>O<br>"
```

and that is what is injected into the `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am new I can't comment so this will have to be in the form of an answer.  So line by line:

```
var str = "Hello";
```

var str is set to equal the string "Hello"

```
var arr = str.split("");
```

var arr is set to equal the var str, but split into segments. In this case each letter.

```
var text = "";
```

var text is just an empty string.

```
var i;
```

var i is an declared variable that is not assigned yet.

```
for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++) { text += arr[i]+"<br>"}
```

The for loop sets i to zero, and as long as i is lower than the length of arr then it will loop and i will increment.  For each iteration the letter stored in arr at position i will be appended to the text variable until i equals the length of arr.

The result is a text of the str variable with line breaks appended to them.  Hopefully that answers the question for you.

Answer (score 1):

In your code there, the `text` variable acts like a "buffer".
The `str` variable gets chopped into a list of characters which is `arr`.

`arr.length` is the number of characters in `arr`, and, each character has a number in this list.

So, your "for" loop states this: "variable 'i' is zero; while 'i' is less than the total number of characters in 'arr', add 1 to 'i'"

`++` means: "increment", it simply adds 1;

in the context of the loop, between the `{ }` braces, you add the current character number of what `i` is from `arr`, and this is then appended each time (for each character) to your `text` variable (buffer) -also with an html "break" `<br>`.

When `i` is no longer smaller than the length of the `arr` array (list), the loop is done, and your `text` contains all the characters; so it is just printed out to the screen.